# Standard string behaviour with characters in C++

Tags: c++, string, std

I have a problem which I do not understand. I add characters to a standard string. Whe I take them out the value printed is not what I expected.

```
int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    string x;
    unsigned char y = 0x89, z = 0x76;
    x += y;
    x += z;
    cout << hex << (int) x[0] << " " <<(int) x[1]<< endl;
}
```

The output:
`ffffff89 76`

What I expected:
`89 76`

Any ideas as what is happening here?
And how do I fix it?

Comment: where is `z` defined ? OK i see it now in the edit.

Comment: Never ever use implicit casts!

Comment: `static_cast` would make no difference

Comment: @Gerhard: so what, you shouldn't use implicit casts anyway, if the casting was the error I would have answered instead of commented ;).

Comment: @KillianDS: There's no such thing as an "implicit cast". Casting is always explicit. There's implicit conversion, but that's not the case here. You're probably talking about C-style cast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to account for the fact that `char` may be signed. If you promote it to `int` directly, the signed value will be preserved. Rather, you first have to convert it to the unsigned type of the same width (i.e. `unsigned char`) to get the desired value, and *then* promote that value to an integer type to get the correct formatted printing.

Putting it all together, you want something like this:

```
std::cout << (int)(unsigned char)(x[0]);
```

Or, using the C++-style cast:

```
std::cout << static_cast<int>(static_cast<unsigned char>(x[0]))
```

Answer (score 4):

The string operator `[]` is yielding a `char`, i.e. a signed value. When you cast this to an `int` for output it will be a signed value also.

The input value cast to a `char` is negative and therefore the `int` also will be. Thus you see the output you described.

Comment: Remember that whether `char` is `signed` or `unsigned` is implementation defined.

Comment: +1: But if the default char type is signed or not is implementation dependent

Comment: this is what i thought too. And i just tested it and that's the case `0x79` is coming out correctly but then onwards its the `ffffffxx`.

Comment: @danishgoel This is because any unsigned char with highest bit not set (i.e. <0x80) will be cast to a positive value, everything above to a negative value.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely `char` is `signed` on your platform, therefore `0x89` and `0x76` become negative when it's represented by `char`.

You've to make sure that the string has `unsigned char` as `value_type`, so this should work:

```
typedef basic_string<unsigned char> ustring; //string of unsigned char!

ustring ux;
ux += y;
ux += z;
cout << hex << (int) ux[0] << " " <<(int) ux[1]<< endl;
```

It prints what you think should print:

```
89 76
```

Online demo : http://www.ideone.com/HLvcv

Comment: `0x76` shouldn't (and doesn't) become negative.

Comment: Also (although not relevant to your point), `basic_string<unsigned char>` is undefined behavior.  A lot of implementations (VC++ and g++, at least) do define it, but not necessarily in the same way.

Comment: @JamesKanze: Why `basic_string<unsigned char>` is undefined behavior?

Comment: Because the standard doesn't define any behavior for it.  `basic_string<unsigned char>` is in fact `basic_string<unsigned char, char_traits<unsigned char> >`.  And the standard only defines (and requires) specializations for `char` and `wchar_t` (in C++03---add `char16_t` and `char32_t` for C++11).  An implementation can provide the definition for a generic version of `char_traits`, or a specialization for `unsigned char`, or neither; in the first two cases, it can define it however it likes.  If you want strings of `unsigned char`, you must define a traits class yourself.

Comment: @JamesKanze: `. If you want strings of unsigned char, you must define a traits class yourself.` Only if the implementation doesn't define it, right? If the implementation doesn't define it, then would it not give compilation error since it would try to instantiate `char_traits<unsigned char>` which is not define.

Comment: Yes.  I should have added an "or use an implementation specific extension".  I know that both VC++ and g++ define a generic version of `char_traits`.  Differently, of course, since neither knows what it really should do (and I don't know where to find the documentation of either).

Answer (score 0):

The number `0x89` is `137` in decimal system. It exceeds `the cap of 127` and is now a negative number and therefore you see those `ffffff`there. You could just simply `insert (unsigned char) after the (int) cast`. You would get the required result.

-Sandip